# Why doesn't $f'(x) \to 0$ at $x \to \infty$ imply that $\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)}$ exists?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

I know there are several examples where $f'(x) \to 0$ at $x \to \infty$, but $f(x)$ is unbounded, like $f(x) = \ln (x)$, but I cannot grasp this logically.

When the slope of a function is tending to zero, doesn't this mean the function itself is approaching a constant value?

Comment: How fast the slope goes to zero matters. If it decays too slowly, it will be too late to bound the function.

Comment: @Gae.S. I think OP wanted intuition for why the fact doesn't hold. They "understand" the counterexample but want to go deeper to "feel" a reason why, and it does lead to more interesting math about convergence rates.

Comment: Slope going to $0$ means adding ever smaller increments to the function value over each interval of unit length, from $1$ to $2$, from $2$ to $3$, and so on. But even increments going to $0$ can accumulate so that their sum grows without bound. It is the same effect as with [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverging. In fact, partial sums of harmonic series grow roughly at the same rate as $\ln x$ over unit intervals.

Comment: +1 to @Conifold. Think of the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. While the components go to zero at infinity, the sum diverges. Then we have an equivalence between the sequence components and a function derivative, as well as between the partial sums and the function value

Comment: @Conifold I understand what you're saying. Would be better if you posted it as an answer so i could accept it.

Comment: @bof then it goes the same for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$? $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x}=\infty$.

Comment: @Invisible Better example: $f(x)=\ln x\sin(\ln x)$

Comment: @bof, then also $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/344938/721644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it seem "intuitively obvious" to you that, if my velocity approaches zero, then my position must approach a limiting value? (Velocity is the derivative of position.) Let me get in my spaceship for this, I'm going to need lots of room. Here's my itinerary.

First I fly $1$ mile north at $1$ mile per hour.
Then I fly $10$ miles south at $0.1$ mph.
Then $100$ miles north at $0.01$ mph.
Then $1000$ miles south at $0.001$ mph.
Then $10000$ miles north at $0.0001$ mph.
And so on, *ad infinitum*.

Graph my position as a function of time. Does the slope approach zero? What limit does the function converge to?

Comment: Thanks!  That example cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

Slope going to $0$ means adding ever smaller increments to the function value over each interval of unit length, from $1$ to $2$, from $2$ to $3$, and so on. But even when the increments go to $0$ they can accumulate so that their sum grows without bound. It is the same effect as with [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverging. In fact, partial sums of harmonic series grow roughly at the same rate as $\ln x$ over unit intervals, $\ln(n+1)-\ln n \sim \frac1n$.

A neat physical illustration of this is that one can stack bricks on top of each other so that the stack is stable, but the top brick hangs over the bottom one as far horizontally as one wishes. Each brick has to be shifted sideways from the previous one by $\frac1{2n}$ of its length, see [Overhang puzzle](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-overhang-puzzle-solution-20161202/). This is even more counterintuitive than a function growing to $\infty$ while its tangent approaches the horizontal.